# Extract list that have number elements from a list of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of lists and I want to remove those lists in which there is no digit element.

Say, l is my list of lists

```
l = [['a', '1 '], ['b', '60.58 '], ['c', '210.96 '], ['d', 'e'], ['f', '200.00 '], ['r','t','u ']]
```

I require l1 as output:

```
l1 = [['a', '1 '], ['b', '60.58 '], ['c', '210.96 '],['f', '200.00 ']]
```

I have already tried:

```
l1 = []
for lists in l:
    for l_1 in lists:
        for element in l_1:
            if any(element.isdigit() for e in element):
                l1.append(l_1)
```

This extracts all the numbers
Thank you in advance!

Comment: try appending variable - `lists` instead of `l_1` in the last line.

Comment: @Yogaraj Yes, I did this. Though ```l1``` has duplicates and I don't wnt dupliactes. For now, I have removed them explicitlly but can this be avoided while appending ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify above logic by using `str.isdigit()` inside *list comprehension* with `any()` to get desired list as
:

```
my_list = [['a', '1 '], ['b', '60.58 '], ['c', '210.96 '], ['d', 'e'], ['f', '200.00 '], ['r','t','u ']]

new_list = [l for l in my_list if any(c.isdigit() for s in l for c in s)]

# where `new_list` will hold:
# [['a', '1 '], ['b', '60.58 '], ['c', '210.96 '], ['f', '200.00 ']]
```

Comment: I might have not explained it well, I needed even the combination to be taken a ```True```. But, thank you

Comment: @M_Arora That makes it even simpler. Updated the answer to fit your use-case

Answer (score 0):

```
l1 = []
for lists in l:
    for l_1 in lists:
        for element in l_1:
            if any(element.isdigit() for e in element):
                l1.append(lists)
```

It was a silly mistake. I had to append `lists` instead of `l_1`.

Answer (score 0):

As the list of elements which have digits contain trailing spaces, we need to check if it could be converted to float or not. You can try this:

```
l1 = []
for i in l:
    for j in range(0, len(i)):
        temp = i[j].strip()
        try:
            temp2 = float(temp)
            l1.append(i)
        except:
            pass
print(l1)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. we can delimit a function to check a list have or not have digit

   ```
   import re
   def have_digit(arr):
   for i in arr:
       if bool(re.search(r'\d', i)) == True:
           return arr
   return None
   ```
2. then, we can transfer the function with iteration

   ```
   l_new = []
   l = [['a', '1 '], ['b', '60.58 '], ['c', '210.96 '], ['d', 'e'], ['f', '200.00 '], 
        ['r','t','u ']]
   for i in l:
       data = have_digit(i)
       if data != None:
           l_new.append(data)`
       data = have_digit(i)
       if data != None:
           l_new.append(data)
   ```